# Como informar dados em um vetor

Tags: java, array, loop

Não estou conseguindo informar 10 notas de alunos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] N = new double[10];
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<N.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Informe a Nota");
            N[] = scn.nextDouble();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apenas uma Observação: você não está seguindo a convenção de nomenclatura do Java, nomes de Classe devem começar com letra maiúscula (`Exer` ao invés de `exer`), e, os nomes de variáveis começam com letra minúscula (`n` ao invés de `N`).

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: respondi sim que funcionou. Vlw, mas sou iniciante aqui porisso nao frequento muito hehe

Comment: Já fez o tour, @user90625 ? Ele ensina a aceitar as questões. Clique no "v" verde que aparece logo abaixo da votação. Você ganha até mesmo 2 pontos de reputação por aceitar uma questão

Answer (score 1):

Você criou um `vetor` de 10 posições, então você deve informar em qual posição você deseja escrever um valor.

#### Exemplo

```
String[] Carros = new String[3];
Carros[2] = "Gol"; // A última posição vai conter o valor: Gol
Carros[0] = "HB20"; // A Primeira posição vai conter o valor: HB20
```

A solução para seu problema é alterar a linha:

```
N[] = scn.nextDouble();
```

Para:

```
N[i] = scn.nextDouble();
```

Referência: [Um pouco de arrays](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/um-pouco-de-arrays/)

Comment: mas nesse caso, ja esta definido cada vetor nao eh??
eu preciso informar os dados e preencher o vetor de 10 posicao :( ??

Comment: Ali é só um exemplo, dentro do `for` altere `N[] ` para `N[i]` que irá funcionar como você deseja.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar um variável como índice assim como o próprio nome diz o índice vai variando a cada passagem pelo laço. No caso o que está variando de acordo com o laço é a variável `i`. Tem formas ligeiramente diferentes de fazer isto.

Aproveitei e melhorei algumas coisas:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class exer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] N = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe a Nota");
            N[i] = scn.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/58dDEl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/idjswpfo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Index.java).

Comment: vlw! muito obrigado

Comment: @user90625 veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.